# How to receive an email notification on builds generated by scheduled triggers in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Following is the screenshot for my scheduled build triggers in VSTS:
[image]

I do get an email when I manually queue a build or push anything to the branch. I didn't receive an email after the scheduled build trigger. Is there a setting which I need to enable to receive the email about the status of the build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add **A build completes** subscription, so that you can always get email notifications when the build completes (no matter the build is triggered manually or scheduled).

Detail setting as below:

In Notifications page https://account.visualstudio.com/_notifications, check if you have **A build completes** subscription. If not, add this subscription:

Specify the email address(es) you want to receive notification -> spectify the team project (or any team project) -> Save.

[image]

Now for the schedule triggered build, you can also receive the email notification for build status.

[image]
[image]

Comment: More context: default build status notification covers only builds that are manually queue/triggered. More info: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162946/no-email-notification-is-sent-after-a-build-comple.html

Comment: @SiburNY Thanks, that worked for me... adding my own notification with specifically only my email address. Now I get build failure messages from scheduled runs.

Comment: This didn't work for me even though I created [a custom organization-wide notification](https://i.imgur.com/BxudasO.png). I still only get messages for builds triggered by myself.